# How do I use python libraries inside django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to execute various commands and display/process their output to a django template. For example:

- I want to ping a host (or IP) and see If it's active/turned on. Then display "ONLINE" on an html page
- I want to execute a whois to a domain, grab the owner's country and display it on page
- I want execute an nslookup, or an nmap and parse several things from the outputs

All I am searching for is a mindset to think on. I'm stuck where I `import subprocess` inside views.py and do not know how to go on. How should I continue ?

Comment: It's really hard to tell where your problem is. If you want to use a library, you import it and use it, just like any code. Where is your confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ping a host on linux from a Django view:

```
import subprocess

def view(request):
    try:
        subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '1', "1.2.3.4"])
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        host_online = False
    else:
        host_online = True

    return render(request, "template.html", {'online': host_online,})
```

This runs the command `ping -c 1 1.2.3.4` which will try to ping the host once only.  `ping` will exit with a return code of 0 if it succeeded, and 1 if it did not. `subprocess.check_call(...)` translates that 1 or 0 into an exception or no exception (respectively).

This solution will cause the page load to be held up while the ping is in progress, which will be a few seconds if the host is in fact down.  If that is a problem, consider instead putting the ping in a view that is requested via AJAX from the page once it has loaded.

You can do similar things for your other commands.

Comment: What about "CalledProcessError" ? I am getting an error message.

Comment: Please don't post untested code. You're missing the import of `CalledProcessError`, a closing bracket `]` after the IP address, `host_online` will always be `False`, ...

Comment: Sorry, not actually tried the code, I *think* my edit will fix the problem you've got. If not, I'll try it properly when I'm not using my phone!

Comment: This is unbelievable (to me), it really works ! I will try it with an ajax request also. What If you want to parse the country of a whois for another example ?

Comment: There are a few ways to do whois in python. One is to take a similar approach and use with `output = subprocess.check_output(['whois', ...])`, and parse the resulting output yourself, however the best thing to do for whois is to use something like [`pywhois`](https://code.google.com/p/pywhois/). I would have suggested that approach for ping too, but 1. pinging from pure python requires root privalages and 2. you were asking about subprocess in your question.

Comment: @RobDel try googling around for a how to do those things in python in general, then just implement them in a Django view.